# How do I import the css of my tumblr on my tumblr posts on my website?

Tags: css, web, import, tumblr

This is the website with my tumblr posts
http://kian02.comlu.com/kian4.php
I was able to get the tumblr posts by using this script,

but I also want to import the styling of my actual tumblr too.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Most tumblr theme's have their CSS code contained in style tags in the html document (there's varying reasons for this, but it's standard practise).

Because of this, you'll have to make sure that you copy ALL the css in the theme (contained in the HTML file, and elsewhere if applicable) and copy it into a new css file that you'll host yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I also wanted to see if I could get the comments showing up too.

Comment: Tumblr doesn't natively support comments, instead some themes make use of a third party service that integrates nicely with Tumblr (this is one of Tumblr's main drawbacks). If you wanna look into pulling comments, you'll have to make your way to www.disqus.com and have a look at their API - it's the system used when one wants comments on your tumblr blog :)

Answer (score 0):

Download it and upload them there. Then just link it in the template by adding before `</head>` this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_the_place_where_you_uploaded_yout_css.css">`